Fantasy manga where the main character is the demon king who is killed by the hero female lead, but prepared reincarnation magic
The main character (MC) is the demon king and the hero is the female lead. She kills the MC in their battle, but the MC prepared reincarnation magic and reincarnated in a temple, but became level 1 and lost all his strength.
The manga was in black and white. It wasn't an isekai. The MC is male and the hero female. I think the MC had a system after reincarnation. I found it on a random manga site. I only read like 1-2 chapters. It was like 2 years ago last I saw it.

If she's the female lead, does that mean she's still appears after the protagonist reincarnates? Do you remember why/how? Is she part of this temple? Or his mother in the new life?

No his body just formed inside the temple with clothes there Was a woman who appeared when he reincarnated don't remember if she's the hero
